# send and receive strings through http connection in android

Tags: java, android, http, arduino

I will try to keep my question simple..
using an arduino and an ethernet shield i have succesfully set up an http server. over a telnet interface i can send and receive strings between the server and my computer, and that's all i want. But i want to do it over an android application. 
i've done my searching and i've found that the simplest connection to an http server is by httpUrlConnection. But i have not managed to get it through.
Everywhere i searched there was the same exmple but i had problems with writeStream() and readStream().. just to be clear i do not want to use complicated methods like post, get, put etc etc, i just want to send and receive strings.
thanks in advance,
Loukas

edit:sorry but after some search i found out i can use http client and not http url connection because i have set up a server at the arduino. my question now is how can i simulate telnet through http, i have found only examples tha use sockets, i want to use httpclient and just send and receive stings like telnet, thanks and i am really sorry i cannot be more clear..

Comment: Did you enable the `INTERNET` permission when you tried?

Comment: yeap, i did, i can have a connection through my application, i just can't handle the data give and take.. :S

Comment: so where exactly is your problem? which part of the code snippets you were looking for didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I can't see the "writeStream" or "readStream" routines in your app. If you made a copy-paste from somewhere, you might want to look at the definitions for those functions...

I googled for an example that looked similar to yours and found this, not sure if it'll help:

http://pastebin.com/gE650RrS

In a nutshell: you need to create those methods.

Comment: sorry but after some search i found out i can use http client and ton http url connection because i have set up a server at the arduino. my question now is how can i simulate telnet through http, i have found only examples tha use sockets, i want to use httpclient and just send and receive stings like telnet, thanks and i am really sorry i cannot be more clear..